# Update object values inside array where id is equal to inside Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Supposedly I want to update the object values of array of a document, but first I will need to look for its id first, heres the structure of document

```json
{
_id: ObjectId('12312')
notifications: [
       {
         _id: ObjectId('1')
          status: 'unread'
       },
       {
         _id: ObjectId('2')
          status: 'unread'
       },
       {
         _id: ObjectId('3')
          status: 'unread'
       }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the status of notifications under that user where the objectId must be equal to inside the result array

```json
result = 
  [
  new ObjectId("1"),
  new ObjectId("2"),
  ]
```

this should yield this result after the update

```json
{
_id: ObjectId('12312')
notifications: [
       {
         _id: ObjectId('1')
          status: 'read'
       },
       {
         _id: ObjectId('2')
          status: 'read'
       },
       {
         _id: ObjectId('3')
          status: 'unread'
       }
    ]
}
```

Heres what Ive done so far but Im not getting the result i need

```js
  const updateuser = await User.updateMany({_id:idofuser, "notifications._id": { $in : result }},{
     $set: {
            "notifications.$.status": "read",
         }
   })
```

Comment: `ObjectId('1')` of you is an object, you need a function that compares objects before merging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$map` to iterate through `notifications` and use `$cond` and `$mergeObjects` to perform the conditional update.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "12312"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "notifications": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$notifications",
          "as": "n",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$n._id",
                  [
                    "1",
                    "2"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$n",
                  {
                    "status": "read"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "else": "$$n"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HDJk5MpVwCX) for your reference.

Comment: Hello sir thankyou for that answer, but may I ask, what is the purpose of multi property in the aggregate

Comment: @JASMAL actually not really useful for your case. It is just there for demonstrating a more general usage. You can check out its usage through [this official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-update-multi)

Comment: @JASMAL I guess I can elaborate more. Your criteria specify by `_id`. As `_id` must be unique, there will be at most 1 document being matched. The `multi` option is hence not required as it is only required when multiple documents are required to be updated.